# How to perform automatic array reshaping in Julia?

Tags: julia

In the Numpy I can say:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.arange(10)
>>> arr.reshape((2, -1))
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
```

In the preceding code block, the `-1` means "what ever is needed". How can I do the same thing in Julia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In julia, we can use [`:`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Base.reshape) instead of `-1` in Numpy:

```
julia> arr = [0:9...];

julia> reshape(arr, 2, :)
2×5 Matrix{Int64}:
 0  2  4  6  8
 1  3  5  7  9
```

If I want to achieve the same thing as Numpy's output:

```
julia> permutedims(reshape(arr, :, 2))
2×5 Matrix{Int64}:
 0  1  2  3  4
 5  6  7  8  9
```